# Cumulated amount of event in Firebase A/B testing

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I had made new menu for my app and I have made A/B testing to optimize my revenue. I have set ad_impression as a goal.
I see in A/B testing console that new menu is worse for ad_impression:

￼[image]

I have logged those two group of users with User Properties too and I have notices that my revenue is better with new ("card") menu:

￼
￼
 [image]
[image]

Does A/B test just say me what version is better for at least one ad_impression for user? How can I test for cumulated amount of event occurrences (A/B test doesnt take into account that with new version more users will use the app in the long run and so on)? If so, testing for ad_impressions and other ad events are nearly pointless for my case. Do you have any plans to add the option to see cumulated amount of event occurrences like in funnels and optimize for revenue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is only possibility to get this information is from BigQuery (it is described in official video https://youtu.be/YGxrAB1MNEY?t=400)